# How can I disable input using X libraries from a C++ application

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, x11

I am making an application for Raspberry Pi and when the application is run all the clicks and keyboard presses aren't contained in the application - they 'go through' to the desktop causing other things to be clicked and typed into in behind the application. From what I've found so far I think I need to be using the `X11` libraries to disable input. I can use `xinput` to disable input from the command line and I understand I could just call system( "`xinput` command to disable input" ) but `xinput` is just doing some c functions so ideally I could just do this directly from my application code. From looking at the `xinput` code, I can see that `XChangeDeviceProperty()/XIChangeDeviceProperty()` functions are being used but I can't quite figure out how to use these in isolation from my application.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to disable all input? If you only want your click and keyboards events to not 'fall through' the window just take a look at the `XSelectInput` function.